# UDF for calculating median of a column in a table - pl/sql

Tags: plsql

Please help me.

I need an UDF for calculating median of a column (salary) in ascending order.

I **only** need **user defined function** for calculating median.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! I would recommend taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first, reading on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), reading on [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and finally I would highly recommend reading [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: We don't mind homework questions, but we do expect you to take some time and effort before posting it to get yourself familiar with SO, to do a good faith attempt at solving your problem before asking and finally to ask it in such a way where you are looking for a help on a part you are actually stuck, not expecting us to solve your homework for you.

Comment: Also fix your tags, if you are using SQL-Server tag it appropriately with `sql-server` tag, don't use 2 separate tags as SQL and Server as that means something else entirely

Comment: Please see why [can someone help me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/) is not a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A general query to find a median value is to use one of the windowing functions :

- PERCENTILE_CONT
- PERCENTILE_DISC

With the WITHIN GROUP clause associated.

As an example, to find the median salay from a table of salary, you can write :

```
SELECT *, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY salary) OVER () AS MEDIAN_SALARY
FROM SalariesTable
```

Comment: but that's query
i want a user defined function

Comment: This is impossible to have ONLY a function because a median needs a set based computation, not a row calculus...